# Telegram error 409. How to solve?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

When typing https://api.telegram.org/botmy bot token/getupdates i get error 409 (another webhook is active). How to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Quoted from [Telegram-Bot-Api](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getting-updates),

> Notes

1. You will not be able to receive updates using getUpdates for as long as an outgoing webhook is set up.

To solve this, delete the webhook you did setup using your bot-token by simply providing no url:
`https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/setWebhook`

let's say, your bot-token: `12345:abxef3ed`

So, you just perform this:
`https://api.telegram.org/bot12345:abxef3ed/setWebhook`

make sure you wrote 'bot' before token, not only token itself!

*I know this is too late for you, but may help others.

Comment: @WiseStrawberry, just for your case it does not work(I wonder why not) you cast a downvote!!!??

Comment: I use telegraf-js, and this doesnt fix it, i keep getting the same response when starting up my bot, I'd love to give you an upvote but for me personally it didnt do anything.

What is supposed  to happen/what is the expected response? 

I can only start my bot new if i delete the old api token.

The downvote is more of a frustration with my bot than an attack on your answer :)

Comment: I think you are following something else as you are saying starting up your bot(I assume). If possible follow their rest api  I have mentioned in my answer and this thread q/a is for webhook.

Comment: do you mean a webhook? Because im following multiple webhooks that are not telegram, is that something that is not going right?

I'm gonna check again. I re-applied the +1 to your question

Comment: yes, this q/a thread is about webhook problem and solutions are provided based on that. To activate and get data from your bot register webhook, if not needed, just clear that hook as mentioned in the answer. You can follow their [RES API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api)

Answer (score -1):

Solution

Go to https://api.telegram.org/botmy bot token/setwebhook and now try to go ttps://api.telegram.org/botmy bot token/setupdates .